# Return json response in laravel 4 filter

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I want to return a 401 error with a message if an user is not logged in. Here is my filter and the route to which it will be applied:

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
  if (!Auth::check())
    {
      return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Please log in.'), 401);
    } 
});

Route::get('/books',  array('before' => 'auth', function() {
...
}));
```

I copied the code from a tutorial, so basically it should work. But I am getting this error:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8000/books"
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":
"Call to   undefined method Illuminate\\Http\\Response::json()","line 42"
```

Is it not possible to return JSON objects using a filter?

**Edit**:
I have the same response in one of my Laravel controllers and it works.

Comment: Don't you see that it tries to call undefined method? Check if it exists in that particular class and if you're loading proper namespace.

Comment: You are trying to call an undefined method. Please post the portion of your coce where this method is defined.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I am using a special response of laravel. So I don't think that I have to define the function. see: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why I can use Response.json() in my controllers, but not in my filters. But in the API I saw JsonResponse and that worked for me:

```
return JsonResponse::create(array('flash' => 'Please log in.'), 401);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve in **Laravel 4** this by using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` - [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses). Take a look at this simple code snippet - `return Response::json([]);`.

#### Usage in filter:

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json([
             'flash' => 'Please log in.'
        ], 401);
    }
});
```

#### Usage in controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

/**
 * Class ReportController
 * @package App\Modules\Moderation\Controllers
 */
class ExampleController extends BaseController
{

    // ################### class methods // ###############################

    /**
     * Create post action
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function someAction()
    {
        return Response::json([
            'id' => 1337,
            'name' => 'Bob',
            'gender' => 'male'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line :

```
return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Please log in.'), 401);
```

with this one :

```
return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Please log in.', 401));
```

I belive the jsno method accepts an array, an you were providing an array and a second parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I am getting the same error. But I have the same piece of code in one of my Laravel controllers and there it works.